Calculating camera position with different altitudes
I've been implementing the concept from this mapbox blog to animate 3d routes from GPS activities into my fitness app - Trackster
Everything works great for GPS activities that are at ~sealevel. When the altitude increases, it gets increasingly skewed.
Feels like I'm just not understanding why the altitude is throwing off the newly calculated coordinates by so much?? Here is the algorithm used to get the camera position.
computeCameraPosition(
  pitch,
  bearing,
  targetPosition,
  altitude,
  previousCameraPosition = null,
  smooth = false
) {

  function lerp(start, end, amt) {
    return (1 - amt) * start + amt * end
  }

  var bearingInRadian = bearing / 57.29;
  var pitchInRadian = (90 - pitch) / 57.29;
  var altFac = (altitude / Math.tan(pitchInRadian))

  var d = Math.cos( target
  var lngDiff = ( altFac * Math.sin(-bearingInRadian)) / d;

  var correctedLng = targetPosition.lng + (lngDiff);
  var correctedLat = targetPosition.lat - (latDiff);

  const newCameraPosition = {
    lng: correctedLng,
    lat: correctedLat
  };

  if (smooth) {
    if (previousCameraPosition) {
      const SMOOTH_FACTOR = 0.9
      newCameraPosition.lng = lerp(newCameraPosition.lng, previousCameraPosition.lng, SMOOTH_FACTOR);
      newCameraPosition.lat = lerp(newCameraPosition.lat, previousCameraPosition.lat, SMOOTH_FACTOR);
    }
  }

  return newCameraPosition
},


Please see [ask] about [mre]. Links to an external Google Drive aren't that useful.

You are using wrong formula to adjust the camera (altFac and latDiff) because this does not correctly factor in the curvature of the Earth at higher altitudes and thus altitude is skewing your camera position.
The main problem is that you are calculating the horizontal distance using altFac = (altitude/Math.tan(pitchInRadian)), and which will never work at higher altitudes and this calculation introduces an errors.
I have tried to code the same as per my perspective, just check I think this will resolve your query.

    computeCameraPosition(
      pitch,
      bearing,
      targetPosition,
      altitude,
      previousCameraPosition = null,
      smooth = false
    ) {
      function lerp(start, end, amt) {
        return (1 - amt) * start + amt * end;
      }
    
      const R = 6371000;
      const bearingInRadian = bearing / 57.29;
      const pitchInRadian = (90 - pitch) / 57.29;
      const altFac = (altitude / Math.tan(pitchInRadian));
    
      const d = Math.cos(targetPosition.lat / 57.29) * R;
    
      const latDiff = (altFac * Math.cos(bearingInRadian)) / R;
      const lngDiff = (altFac * Math.sin(-bearingInRadian)) / (d / R);
    
      const correctedLng = targetPosition.lng + (lngDiff * (180 / Math.PI));
      const correctedLat = targetPosition.lat + (latDiff * (180 / Math.PI));
    
      const newCameraPosition = {
        lng: correctedLng,
        lat: correctedLat
      };
    
      if (smooth) {
        if (previousCameraPosition) {
          const SMOOTH_FACTOR = 0.9;
          newCameraPosition.lng = lerp(newCameraPosition.lng, previousCameraPosition.lng, SMOOTH_FACTOR);
          newCameraPosition.lat = lerp(newCameraPosition.lat, previousCameraPosition.lat, SMOOTH_FACTOR);
        }
      }
    
      return newCameraPosition;
    }


Although I have mentioned the code but it may still require small fine-tuning depending on your specific use case like very high altitudes or how Mapbox interprets your data.
In case of any further help let me know.
